# preg_match must end with "/"?

Tags: php, preg-match

In the preg_match below, I'm comparing against two static strings, $url and $my_folder...

```
  $url = get_bloginfo('url')
//$url = 'http://site.com'

  $my_folder = get_option('my_folder');
//$my_folder = 'http://site.com/somefolder;
```

I'm getting a match when the $my_folder string has a trailing slash

```
 http://somefolder/go/
```

But this does not create a match...

```
 http://somefolder/go
```

However, another problem is that this also matches...

```
 http://somefolder/gone
```

Code is...

```
$my_folder =  get_option('rseo_nofollow_folder');
if($my_folder !=='') $my_folder = trim($my_folder,'/');
$url = trim(get_bloginfo('url'),'/');

preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);

for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){
    if($my_folder !=='')
    {
    //HERES WHERE IM HAVING PROBLEMS

        if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i]) 
            && (preg_match('~' . $my_folder . '/?$~', $matches[0][$i]) 
            || !preg_match( '~'. $url .'/?$~',$matches[0][$i])))
        {
            $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
            $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
            $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //THIS WORKS FINE, NO PROBLEMS HERE
        if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i]) && (!preg_match( '~'.$url.'~',$matches[0][$i]))) 
            {
            $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
            $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
            $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
            }
    }
}
return $content;
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what the `$my_folder` and `get_bloginfo` values are.

Comment: It would not be wrong to use `preg_quote`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: @netcoder: I've updated the question with values for those variables. THanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`~^http://somefolder/go(?:/|$)~`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first remove the trailing slash and add '/?' at the end of your regexp

```
$my_folder = trim($my_folder,'/');
$url = trim(get_bloginfo('url'),'/');

if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i]) 
    && (preg_match('~' . $my_folder . '/?$~', $matches[0][$i]) 
    || !preg_match( '~'. $url .'/?$~',$matches[0][$i])))
```

Comment: its almost there, but matches somefolder/gone too (match should be somefolder/go or go/ but not /gone

Comment: Did you put the $ at the end of your regex as in my example?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it exactly. Take a look back at my question. I've updated it with more explanation. I think your regex has defeated all of my exceptions (it matches internal links that have $url in them but not folder) :) Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Now you've posted more code I can see many problems... First, attempting to parse a whole HTML page with regex is a bad idea. Second, you're matching the whole content of the <a> tag against a URL. So if your regex is `~http://somefolder/go/?$~` it will never match `<a href="http://somefolder/go/">`. I would recommend using a DOM parser to process your HTML. It may be a little heavier that regexes but will be much sturdier and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but try:

```
preg_match( '/' . preg_quote( get_bloginfo('url'), '/' ) . '?/', $matches[0][$i] )
```

You can use whatever char you want in place of the `/` chars. I'm guessing that you're using wordpress and guessing that `get_bloginfo('url')` is normalized to always have a trailing slash. If that is the case, the last slash will be selected optionally by the `?` at the end of the regex.

Comment: yes WordPress, but the trailing slash on bloginfo('url') is not the norm in my experience.

Comment: Replace all 3 conditions with your single? Needs to match (1) not already a nofollow (2) not an internal link (2) in the form of the $my_folder string (with or without a trailing slash). So any external link that's not already nofollow, gets nofollow, as well as any link matching the $my_folder pattern.

Comment: i thought the issue was that it wasn't matching on the third item.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `strstr()` or `strpos()` if it's fixed strings anyway.

Your example rewritten:

```
if (!strstr($matches[0][$i], "nofollow") 
 and strstr($matches[0][$i], $my_folder) 
 or !strstr($matches[0][$i], $url)  )
```

strpos works similarly, but you need an extra boolean check:

```
if (strpos($matches, "nofollow") === FALSE
 or strpos($matches, $my_folder) !== FALSE)
```

Comment: I haven't used strstr() before. Do you have an example that replaces my preg_match?

Comment: @Scott: See edit. strstr($subject, $find) simply returns the found string (=true) if the search string is discovered.

Comment: very close, except I still get a match on site.com/gone, when folder is site.com/go

Comment: @Scott: Didn't see that you actually have a delimiter. But since you are matching the href= attribute, there might be a simple trick. Try `strstr($m, "$my_folder\"") or strstr($m, "$my_folder/\"")` which might work for properly enclosed attributes.